# How can i get the values of android preferences correctly? Personal error

Tags: android

I will get the values of the preferences with this code but when i show the value of one, the value obtained is the default value, like "false", "vectorial" or "1". 
I will show the actual value of the preference. 
I know, the question exist in stackoverflow. But not help me.
My code to read preferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);             
                boolean musica = prefs.getBoolean("musica", false);
                String graficos =prefs.getString("graficos", "vectorial"); 
                int Fragmentos = prefs.getInt("fragmentos",1);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    String.valueOf(Fragmentos), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The preferences xml exist and is tested.
The preferences xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:key="preferencias_principal" >
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Asteroides" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="musica"
        android:summary="Se reproduce música de fondo"
        android:title="Reproducir música" />

    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:entries="@array/tiposGraficos"
        android:entryValues="@array/tiposGraficosValores"
        android:key="graficos"
        android:summary="Se escoge la representación de gráficos"
        android:title="Tipo de gráficos" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:defaultValue="3"
        android:key="fragmentos"
        android:summary="En cuantos trozos se divide un asteroide"
        android:title="Número de Fragmentos" />
</PreferenceCategory>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="Modo multijugador" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="multijugador"
        android:summary="Activa modo multijugador"
        android:title="Activar modo multijugador" />

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="max_jugadores"
        android:summary="Número máximo de jugadores"
        android:title="Máximo de jugadores" />

    <ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="1"
        android:entries="@array/multijugador"
        android:entryValues="@array/multijugador_valores"
        android:key="tipo_conexion"
        android:summary="Tipo de conexión"
        android:title="Tipo de conexión" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

How can i do this?

*Sorry for my english*

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `PreferenceManager#getDefaultSharedPreferences()` to retrieve your application's settings `SharedPreferences`. See [this article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#ReadingPrefs).

Answer (score 1):

Your app's preferences used in the PreferenceActivity are saved to a file that can be accessed by calling PreferenceManager#getDefaultSharedPreferences(). You should therefore

**Change:**

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

**to:**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
```

Read [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) for more

Comment: With the code 
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());    
     boolean musica = prefs.getBoolean("musica", false);
     String graficos =prefs.getString("graficos", "vectorial"); 
     int Fragmentos = prefs.getInt("fragmentos",1);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(Fragmentos), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

the app fail and exit.

Comment: What error is being thrown? post the stack trace error report

Comment: I don´t know. I´m testing on smartphone with 4.2.1 and when i push on a button for activate toast for show the value, the app fail and exit.
I think my problem is in (getApplicationContext()). I´m super noob on android.

Comment: You can also call PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this) or (YourActivity.this)  but I don't think that's the issue. If you are on eclipse, go to logcat, at the right change verbose to error and click save(disk icon) when your app crashes and update your question adding the error report

Comment: If i use getDefaultSharedPreferences(this), eclipse adverts that:
The method getDefaultSharedPreferences(Context) in the type PreferenceManager is not applicable for the arguments (new View.OnClickListener(){}). 
With getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this) no errors appears but the app crash on click the button to view the preference.
In the logcat i can´t see the error, this does not stop runing.

Comment: The app crashes but doesn't stop running. I don't get u. You can set a breakpoint and trace the error. perhaps it's something else causing the error